# Manage iOS Developer Enterprise Programs for several companies

Tags: ios, enterprise

I am a sole trader and I have developed an iPad app that I'm going to sell to several companies independently.
They are small companies (<50 employees) that have nothing to do with IT and it would be a nightmare for them to register with the Developer Enterprise Program.

That's why I'm probably going to register for each of them.

1- Can I register for several Enterprise Programs with my Apple ID, or does it have to be done by someone inside the companies (with a different ID each time that then adds me as as admin)?

2- In that case, am I going to be able to register on their behalf (if they provide me with their apple id + password? or if I appoint myself as the contact for Apple?)

3- Do I even need that program to deploy less than 100 apps to iPads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the Enterprise Program, unless you want to deploy everything on the iTunes store.

In terms of if you can register for several Enterprise Programs, a single organization can enroll in up to five iOS Developer Enterprise Programs.  However, each Enterprise distribution provisioning profile can only be associated with one App ID.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034495/apple-enterprise-program-distribution-questions) Stackoverflow post should help.

Answer (score -3):

you may need to register different  program , then each program invite your appleid as an admin.